# Yii2 REST create with fields()

Tags: api, rest, yii2

Let's say that I had the following API set up:

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii;

class ResourceController extends \yii\rest\ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\modules\v1\models\Resource';
}
```

Model:

```
use yii;

class Resource extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'ResourceTable';
    }

    public function fields()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ResourceID',
            'title' => 'ResourceTitle',
        ];
    }
}
```

where my table only has the two columns, `ResourceID` and `Title`.

When I try a `GET` request on the API, it works fine and returns the list of resources (or single resource in the case of `resource/{id}`) with the aliased field names. But when I try to `POST` to create a resource, I want to use the aliased field names (e.g. `title` instead of `ResourceTitle`). The problem is that the default `CreateAction` supplied by Yii does `$model->load()`, which looks for the field names in the table. If I use the aliased names then it returns an error. If I use the table field names, it works fine.

So my question is, is there a way to expose resource attributes to the end user where the field names (using the `fields()` function) are the same for reading and creating? If possible, I'd like to avoid writing my own CreateAction.

Comment: field names inside validation errors can be changed by overwriting addError() method. Ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220654/yii2-overriding-fields-to-rename-fields-in-case-of-validation-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create getters/setters for alias.

```
public function getTitle(){ return $this->ResourceTitle; }
public function setTitle($val){ $this->ResourceTitle = $val ; }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's necessary to add rules for new virtual properties, if you want to $model-load() save parameters to them

```
class OrganizationBranch extends BaseOrganization{

public function rules()
    {
        return array_replace_recursive(parent::rules(),
        [
            [['organizationId', 'cityId'], 'safe'],
        ]);
    }

    public function fields() {
        return ['id', 
                'cityId' => 'city_id',
                'organizationId' => 'organization_id', 
                'address', 
                'phoneNumbers' => 'phone_numbers', 
                'schedule', 
                'latitude',         
                'longitude',
        ];
    }

    public function extraFields() {
        return ['branchType', 'city'];
    }

    public function getOrganizationId() {
        return $this->organization_id;
    }

    public function setOrganizationId($val) {
        $this->organization_id = $val;
    }

    public function getCityId() {
        return $this->city_id;
    }

    public function setCityId($val) {
        $this->city_id = $val;
    }

}
```