# Yii2 overriding fields() to rename fields in case of validation errors

Tags: rest, api, validation, yii2, field

Ref: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#overriding-fields

I am overriding fields() to rename fields in User model.

GET - response data fields are renamed as expected

POST - validation error field names are not renamed

### 1. User table columns

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['User_Name', 'Password', 'Auth_Token', 'User_Type_Id', 'User_Status_Id'], 'required'],
    ]
}
```

### 2. overriding fields()

```
public function fields()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => 'User_Id',
        'access_token' => 'Auth_Token',
        'user_name' => 'User_Name',
        'user_type' => 'userType.User_Type_Name',
        'name' => 'userProfile.Fname',
    ];
}
```

### 3. Get User data (fields renamed as expected)

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "1",
    "access_token": "123",
    "user_name": "kiran",
    "user_type": "Customer",
    "name": "customer"
  }
]
```

4. Validate model (error field names are not renamed)

   ---

> ```
>  [
>     {
>       "field": "User_Name",
>       "message": "User  Name cannot be blank."
>     },
>     {
>       "field": "Password",
>       "message": "Password cannot be blank."
>     },
>     {
>       "field": "Auth_Token",
>       "message": "Auth  Token cannot be blank."
>     },
>     {
>       "field": "User_Type_Id",
>       "message": "User  Type  ID cannot be blank."
>     },
>     {
>       "field": "User_Status_Id",
>       "message": "User  Status  ID cannot be blank."
>     }
> ]
> ```

Comment: Have you tried to set validation rules with modified field names instead of original ones?

Comment: yes, Getting unknown property User::user_name

Comment: You probably must overwrite addError() method from Model class.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using getter/setter methods to load the post data inside user model.

Ref: [Yii2 REST create with fields()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663403/yii2-rest-create-with-fields)

2. Overwriting addError() method to change error field name

   ```
   public function addError($attribute, $error = '') {
       $renamed_attr = $this->renamedFields($attribute);
       parent::addError($renamed_attr, $error);
   }
   ```